# Granger Test (Python) Error message - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.6

I am trying to run a granger causality test on two currency pairs but I seem to get this error message in Shell whenever I try and test it. Can anyone please advise?

I am very new to programming and need this to run an analysis for my project. In shell, I am putting -

import ats15
ats15.grangertest('EURUSD', 'EURGBP', 8)

What is going wrong? I have copied the script below.

Thanks in advance.

### Heading ##def grangertest(Y,X,maxlag):

```
"""
Performs a Granger causality test on variables (vectors) Y and X.
The null hypothese is: Does X cause Y ?
Returned value: pvalue, F, df1, df2
"""
# Create linear model involving Y lags only.
n = len(Y)
if n != len(X):
    raise ValueError, "grangertest: incompatible Y,X vectors"
M = [ [0] * maxlag for i in range(n-maxlag)]
for i in range(maxlag, n):
    for j in range(1, maxlag+1):
        M[i-maxlag][j-1] = Y[i-j]

fit = ols(M, Y[maxlag:])
RSSr = fit.RSS

# Create linear model including X lags.
for i in range(maxlag, n):
    xlagged = [X[i-j] for j in range(1, maxlag+1)]
    M[i-maxlag].extend(xlagged)
fit = ols(M, Y[maxlag:])
RSSu = fit.RSS
df1 = maxlag
df2 = n - 2 * maxlag - 1
F = ((RSSr - RSSu)/df1)/(RSSu/df2)
pvalue = 1.0 - stats.f.cdf(F,df1,df2)
return pvalue, F, df1, df2, RSSr, RSSu
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the full traceback, but this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

means what it says.  There's an operand `-` -- the subtraction operator -- and it doesn't know how to handle subtracting an integer from a string.  Why would strings be involved?  Well, you're calling the function with:

```
ats15.grangertest('EURUSD', 'EURGBP', 8)
```

and so you're giving `grangertest` two strings and an integer.  But it seems like `grangertest` expects

```
def grangertest(Y,X,maxlag):
```

two sequences (lists, arrays, whatever) of *numbers* to use as Y and X, not strings.  If `EURUSD` and `EURGBP` are names you've given to lists beforehand, then you don't need the quotes:

```
ats15.grangertest(EURUSD, EURGBP, 8)
```

but if not, then you should pass `grangertest` the lists under whatever name you've called them.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense. So how would I import the lists? Perhaps giving some background as to why i'm doing this would make it easier. Basically, I want to see if movements in one currency pair leave to an increase/decrease in another currency pair, and whether this holds the opposite way round. An example was the EURUSD and EURGBP currency pairs. The granger test is perfect for this but I'm very lost as to how to set this up. How shall I proceed?

Comment: You need to get the data into the program.  Presumably you have those numbers in a file somewhere, so simply read them in and assign them to EURUSD and EURBGP.  It looks like the code you're using already has a `scipy` dependency, so you can probably use `numpy.loadtxt`.

Comment: I should have all the data required in the script. See below:
import numpy 
import scipy
import math 
import curve
import datetime
import lib
import xdate
import tsfns
import ATS.lib.rptfns
import math
import numpy as np
import pylab
from   lib.statistics.matlib import *
from   math import log, pi, sqrt
import numpy
import scipy.stats as stats

Can the data not be extracted from the libraries above?

Comment: All of those are modules.  I'm not familiar with some of them -- `ATS`, for example, or `tsfns` -- so maybe one of them contains USD/GBP currency information as sample data, but I've got no reason to think any of the modules I know about do.  Libraries usually contain functions, and have data only for sample/test purposes.  Do you have some reason to think the data you're looking for would happen to be in one of them?  Is there an example in one of the libraries that you're working off of?

Comment: The only reason I think the information must be there because in my script (I only copied and pasted the granger part of the script) I am able to plot correlation for EURUSD vs EURGBP and also see a curve of the movements in the currency over time, so the data must be accessed from somewhere? I am very unclear as to how to get this data in a form where I can run a granger test on it.

Comment: Yep, if the data's plotting, then it's there somewhere.  Look for what arguments are passed to the plot commands.  Shouldn't take you too long.

Comment: When I found out what module the data is coming from, how would I add it to my granger script? Where does it go?

Answer (score 0):

The input to the `grangertest` function must be two lists of numbers. `grangertest` doesn't know anything about currencies, so passing it currency strings won't work.

You have to fetch the exchange rate data somehow so that you can pass it to `grangertest`. If `EURUSD` and `EURGBP` are variables, then you don't put quotes around them when you pass them to a function (e.g. `ats15.grangertest(EURUSD, EURGBP, 8)`).